# Adding polygon to layer from text file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am completely new to QGIS and to GIS in general. I have start to work my way through the documentation but have a question that I cannot find a answer to. When looking into the documentation related to Data Capturing I find plenty of examples when creating lines and polygons using interactive picking.

If I instead have the data in text file (containing coordinates) how do I import the text file?

I have tried to create a layer from "delimited text files" but I do not want to create a new layer I would like to add this data to an existing layer and in addition add attribute data.

Comment: What data? Is it points, lines, or polygons? Are you joining attribute data to existing shapes, or creating new shapes in addition to the existing ones? It may be a two-step (or more) process - ie first create points out of your csv and save to file, then append that information to your existing point file. More information is needed about your text file and the information it contains, and what geometries you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting it to draw from the csv file just select it, copy it and then paste it into the 1st file.

Otherwise if you have many of these to to set up a postgresql/postGIS DB table to handle the data and load the csv file to the table in the db through a psql COPY cmd.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique identifier field for both the the csv and existing layer. Try join attributes.